# Login Token in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

hello I have a problem witch I have a User model in my Account app and I have a user inside it with this information

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "johndoe",
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "password": "password123"
}
```

my problem is when I POST this JSON data to my LoginView I get this error: (ValueError: Cannot query "johndoe": Must be "User" instance.

```
{
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "password": "password123"
}
```

LoginView:

```
class LoginView(APIView):
    """
    Handle user login.
    """
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request):
        """
        Getting the required information for login.
        """
        try:
            email = request.data["email"]
            password = request.data["password"]

            if not (email and password):
                return Response(data={"error": "Some fields are required."},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
            
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)

            if user.password != password:
                return Response(data={'error': "Password is invalid."},
                                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                                
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

            return Response(data={'token': token.key},
                            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        
        except User.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(data={'error': "User not found."},
                                status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        
        except RequestException:
            return Response(data={"error": "An error occurred. Please check your internet connection."},
                            status=status.HTTP_503_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
```

my User model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    simple_description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="tourist")
    biography = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default="")
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I tried to set my User model as the default of the Django User model but when I wanted to create a superuser for my admin panel, it created a regular user with a long password that I didn't put that

Comment: can you show the whole traceback and the whole `LoginView`?

Comment: Bro my problem was just solved :) , I tried to POST the JSON data again to send you the trackback but it worked, idk how. thanks for your help